# mysql change default character set latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, my.cnf, utf8mb4

I have PHP 5.5.9 and MySQL 5.5.43 Innodb. This is in Kubuntu LTS /etc/mysql/my.cnf

printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($conn));

Current character set: latin1

I've tried

default-character-set = utf8

first but then my mysql server didn't restart

Then I've tried

character-set-server = utf8

then my mysql shell didn't start

How can I rescue this issue? I've managed with 
init_connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
solve the problem for nonroot users, but the charset remains the same (it only displays as nonprivileged users UTF8, it is still Latin1).

And if (a big if) smnd could tell me WHERE should I use utf8mb4? Also in my.cnf file? I had my tables in utf8 and have migrated those with which I am working to utf8mb4 ...

Another Q: IS that applicable for Linux (Kubuntu) server:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3M1Wpw4uOoM

Please help me, thanks, Gregor from lilaum.com

Answer (score 3):

[`mysqli_set_charset('utf8')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php).

`init_connect` is ignored for `root` connections.

`utf8mb4` is effectively a superset of `utf8`. It is needed for Chinese and the new emoji, plus a scattering of obscure character sets.

Comment: Is it possible to do that globally once and for all?

Comment: and utf8mb4 is real utf8 ... I thought I have to change it in mysql, because I've added before to php.ini default_charset = "UTF-8"
but it didn't work. Please update me if (I believe so) is possible to change this directive once and for all server globally, thanks ...

Comment: Globally... in `my.cnf`, this _might_ establish utf8mb4 for _future_ actions:  `character_set_server=utf8mb4`  If you have existing data; that will need to be handled in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) says:

> MySQLnd always assumes the server default charset. This charset is sent during connection hand-shake/authentication, which mysqlnd will use.

MySQLnd is the MySQL native driver included with PHP 5.4 and above.

Unfortunately, I have to confirm that even in my system (PHP 5.6.17 with MySQL 5.5.47 on Debian Jessie 8.3) despite having configured /etc/mysql/my.cnf with the following entries

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

the mysqlnd does not seem to assume the server default charset (utf8) but sets the connection charset to *latin1* with collate *latin1_swedish* (maybe a default value considering MySQL AB was a swedish company).

So, it seems that there's no permanent way to set *utf8* charset when connecting from a PHP application. You have to call

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

after each connection. This could be embedded in a custom 'dbconnect' PHP function in order to provide a sort of abstraction layer.